# Wordpress pagination and Post Navigation not working on home page

Tags: posts, pagination, navigation

Pagination doesn't work for me on homepage but it works on my archive pages, I've checked and my homepage is not a static page, any suggestions on how to solve this?

Below is my index.php

```
    <?php get_header(); global $buzz_options,$buzz_options2;  ?>
<!--Mid Counter Start Here -->
<section class="mid-counter">
   <div class="container">
      <?php //buzz_before_panel(); ?>
      <div class="left-panel">
         <div class="left-panel-inside">
            <?php if($buzz_options2['ticker']['home_enable']){ echo buzz_news_ticker(); } ?>
            <?php buzz_home_top_ads(); ?>
            <div class="top-article">
               <?php global $buzz_used_posts; $featured = get_posts(array('tag' => $buzz_options['featured_tax'],'posts_per_page'=>3,'exclude' => $buzz_used_posts));  ?>
               <div class="top-article-left">
                  <?php $c=1; $article_class=''; foreach($featured as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); $post_id = get_the_ID(); $buzz_used_posts[] = $post_id;
                     if($c==2){ echo '</div> <div class="top-article-right">'; }
                     if($c > 1){ $article_class='top-article-one';  }
                     ?>
                  <?php if($c==1): ?>
                  <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-posts.php') ); ?>
                  <?php else : ?>
                  <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-posts2.php') ); ?>
                  <?php endif;  ?>
                  <?php $c++; endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
               </div>
            </div>
            <?php buzz_home_bottom_ads(); ?>
            <div class="bot-article">
               <?php global $buzz_used_posts; $featured2 = get_posts( array('tag' => $buzz_options['featured_tax'] , 'posts_per_page'=>4,'offset'=>3,'exclude' => $buzz_used_posts));  ?>
               <?php $c=1; $article_class='buzz_bg_cover  top-article-one bot-article-loop'; foreach($featured2 as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); $post_id = get_the_ID(); $buzz_used_posts[] = $post_id; ?>
               <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-posts2.php') ); ?>
               <?php $c++; endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?php buzz_middle_sidebar(); ?>
         <?php  $picks_term = get_term_by('slug',$buzz_options['picks_tax'],'post_tag'); ?>
         <?php buzz_before_editor_picks(); ?>
         <div class="faverate-art editors-picks">
            <h2>Editors Picks <em>Our Favourite <a href="http://mywebsite.com/topics/" style="text-decoration: none"><font color="#939393">Articles</font></a></em> <span><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($buzz_options['picks_tax'],'post_tag'); ?>" title="See All">See All</a></span></h2>
            <div class="faverate-art-inside">
               <?php global $buzz_used_posts; $editor_picks = get_posts(array('tag' => $buzz_options['picks_tax'], 'posts_per_page' =>3,'exclude' => $buzz_used_posts));  ?>
               <?php $c=1; $article_class='faverate-art-loop'; foreach($editor_picks as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); $post_id = get_the_ID(); $buzz_used_posts[] = $post_id;  ?>
               <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-posts4.php') ); ?>
               <?php $c++; endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="faverate-art latest-posts">
            <h1>LATEST NEWS</h1>
            <div class="faverate-art-inside latest_posts">
               <?php global $buzz_used_posts,$latest_query; $c=1; $latest_query = new WP_Query; $latest_posts = $latest_query->query( array('posts_per_page' => 60,'post__not_in' => $buzz_used_posts,'paged' => 1)); ?>
               <?php $article_class='faverate-art-loop'; foreach($latest_posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); $post_id = get_the_ID(); $buzz_used_posts[] = $post_id; ?>
               <?php if($c==4){ buzz_between_latest_news(); } ?>
               <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-posts4.php') ); ?>
               <?php $c++; endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
            <!-- <div id="buzz-loadmore" class="load-more">
               <img src="<?php echo MYWEBSITE_THEME_URI; ?>/images/ring-alt.svg"  />
               <a title="Loading more Stories">Loading more Stories</a>
               <div></div>
            </div> -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo get_sidebar('home'); ?>
   </div>
</section>
<!--Mid Counter End Here -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I also have this from wpbeginner in functions.php

```
    function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return false;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return false;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query var for pagination on a static home page is not `paged`, but rather `page`.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page

Static Front Page

If the pagination is broken on a static front page you have to add the "paged" parameter this way:

```
<?php 
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```